# Unable to add filters to showSaveDialog in electron

Tags: javascript, windows, electron, atom-editor, electron-builder

```
dialog.showSaveDialog((fileName) =>{
  filters: [{  name: "Json",  extensions: ['json']}]
  if(fileName === undefined){
      alert("File Not Saved! Enter a valid file name");
      return;
  }
  var content =  '{"json":"true"}';
  fs.writeFile(fileName,content,(err) =>{
      if(err) console.log(err);
  })
})
```

In my code filters not applied

If I am wrong where should I add my filters code?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you've added the filters inside your callback function, instead of inside your options object. Your code should look like this:

```
dialog.showSaveDialog(

    // Your options object...
    { filters: [{ name: "Json", extensions: ['json'] }] },

    // Your callback function...
    fileName => {
        if ( fileName === undefined ) {
            alert("File Not Saved! Enter a valid file name");
            return;
        }
        var content = '{"json":"true"}';
        fs.writeFile( fileName, content, err => {
            if (err) console.log(err);
        });
    }
);
```